# Cant find Qt designer in PYQT4 in windows

Tags: python, pyqt4

installed PyQt4 through .whl file avialiable from www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ by  Christoph Gohlke.
Cant seem to find the Qt designer tool.

Comment: It's at `sys.prefix\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\designer.exe`